# How to mark checkbox as checked whenever the td is clicked using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table containing N number of tr > td , I have Checkboxes of having class="hrchy-dt-checkboxes", So whenever I click that TD, The checkbox should be checked.

Here is my sample HTML

```
<tr style="height:20.1pt;"><input disabled="disabled" value="" class="dt-checkboxes" id="row_2" type="checkbox"> 
  <td class="td_0_3">1<input disabled="disabled" value="" class="hrchy-dt-checkboxes" id="td_2" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td class="td_0_1">A-1) Efectivo y otros activos líquidos equivalentes</td>
  <td class="td_0_1">18063955860.200008</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td> 
 </tr>
 <tr style="height:20.1pt;"><input disabled="disabled" value="" class="dt-checkboxes" id="row_1" type="checkbox"> 
  <td class="td_0_3">&nbsp;<input disabled="disabled" value="" class="hrchy-dt-checkboxes" id="td_1" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td class="td_0_1">ACTIVO: Total del Sector</td>
  <td class="td_0_1">Importe</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td> 
 </tr>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
if(checkboxClass.indexOf('hrchy-dt-checkboxes')!=-1){
    $('.hrchy-dt-checkboxes:checked').each(function(i){
        var idAttr=$(this).attr('id');
        var selectedTDVal=$(this).parent().text();
        var indexVal=idAttr.substring(idAttr.indexOf('_'),idAttr.length);
        indexVal=indexVal.replace('_','');
        var hrchyIndexId=parseInt(indexVal);
        selectedVal[i]=selectedTDVal;
        hrchyMap[hrchyIndexId]=selectedTDVal;
    });
    selectedVal=[];
}
```

Fromo the above code, Whenever a checkbox is clicked the value will be taken to backend. Need enhancement on this Code.

Thanks

Comment: can you share code snippet to us?

Comment: Hi @KARANLAGALWAR , I have updated please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery Code:** Mark checkbox as checked

```
  $("td").on('click',function(){
        $("this").closest("tr").find(".hrchy-dt-checkboxes").attr('checked',true);
    });
```

---

**Updated :**

Added condition if the checkbox is already checked, then marked as unchecked else checked. Using `.is(":checked")` we get the checkbox status.

```
$("table").on('click', 'td', function() {
  var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
  if (currentRow.find(".hrchy-dt-checkboxes").is(':checked')) {
    currentRow.find(".hrchy-dt-checkboxes").prop("checked", false);
  } else {
    currentRow.find(".hrchy-dt-checkboxes").prop("checked", true);
  }
});
```

**DEMO: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z81fw1uv/2/)**

Comment: Does it matter if a checkbox is **checked** manually (i.e. by clicking with mouse) or programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to check the checkbox. However I don't know if you need to uncheck the checkbox also so not adding that. Do let me know if you need it.

```
// Code goes here
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('.hrchy-dt-checkboxes').parent().parent().click(function(){
  var elem = this;
  var chk = $(this).find('.hrchy-dt-checkboxes')[0];
  $(chk).prop('checked','checked');
})  
});
```

Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/L5ipcTT9Ro0XJm1uLWyR) for the same

**Update**:

Here is the updated code to toggle selection:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('.hrchy-dt-checkboxes').parent().parent().click(function(){
  var elem = this;
  var chk = $(this).find('.hrchy-dt-checkboxes')[0];
  var isChecked = $(chk).prop('checked');
    $(chk).prop('checked',!isChecked);  

})  
});
```

Comment: Hi, Yes I need uncheck options too, Can you provide me!

Comment: Review the updated code. I have also updated plunker for the same.

Answer (score 1):

hope this is what you want

```
$('td').click(function (event) {
if (!$(event.target).is('input')) {
   $('input:checkbox', this).prop('checked', function (i, value) {
    return !value;
   });
}
```

});